# ASP.NET How to upload my website

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

This might seem as very stupid question but i can't find anywhere answer to my question : How to upload my asp.net website to my webhosting or i need a microsoft provided webhosting. Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: You can use a tool like [Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/)

Comment: When you say webhosting I assume you are trying to upload to a third party hosting service. Am i correct?

Comment: Then you can logon to the control panel of your hosting account and find File Manager there or use an third party FTP solution like FileZilla as suggested by @freebird

Comment: Take a look at the following link it explain step by step , how to upload with FileZilla http://www.corelangs.com/html/website/upload-website.html allens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right click publish project file in vs, you have few options to upload it

Answer (score 1):

Use some ftp client to publish your Website Contents to your Server.

You can use **[FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/)** to publish your website contents.

Comment: which content exacly i have to publish, i mean which files

Comment: ISeeSounds: I gave you the answer below, but was downvoted. You get the content when you publish from VS. You have the options to save the content to local folder, or upload to ftp

Comment: @ISeeSounds I think you need to publish necessary folders required for stylsheets scripts images.The bin folder App_Data folder and all the .aspx files.You need not publish designer and code files.

Answer (score 0):

Some web host provides file up-loader to upload your asp.net file through File manager if you are not uploading too many file or large files you can use web based file manager of webhost For example Go daddy have one.Or make an FTP account on webhost and upload it by FTP Client such as Filezila you can download it from http://filezilla-project.org/ you need webhost who provides asp.net hosting